# Scroll till end of the page using appium-android

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

For a hybrid app , I need to scroll till the end of the page. How can I do ?
I am able to scroll to exact element by using driver.scrollTo(); and driver.ScrollToExact();

But I want to scroll the app from top to bottom.
Can anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Test
    public void testScroll()throws Exception
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (driver.findElement(By.name("end_item")).isDisplayed())
            {
                driver.findElement(By.name("end_item")).click();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                verticalScroll();
            }

        }
    }
    public void verticalScroll()
    {
        size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int y_start=(int)(size.height*0.60);
        int y_end=(int)(size.height*0.30);
        int x=size.width/2;
        driver.swipe(x,y_start,x,y_end,4000);
    }
```

This will help you to swipe till end or till whatever position you want.

Comment: Where is "horizontalScroll() ; " method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use coordinates to scroll to the end of the page with even locating the String available on the page. Use this:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(20,y).moveTo(20, 10).release();
action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. What I did is, used the text which is at the bottom of that particular page `("text should be dynamic, it should be constant")` then used the following code

```
String text="ABC";
driver.scrollTo(text);
```

After this code you can perform any action.. for example see the below code

```
String text="ABC";
driver.scrollTo(text);  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='"+text+"']")).click();
```

Comment: But when am using scrollTo() method, getting an error as org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: what java client you are using @naazneen3264, can you use latest java client

Comment: am using latest java client version. java client 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> getAllStudyMaterialName(List<WebElement> elements) {
        List<String> documentTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isStudyMaterialRepeat = false;
        while (true) {
            List<WebElement> titles = elements;
            for (WebElement title : titles) {
                documentTitle.add(title.getText());
            }
            scrollUp(driver);
            if (documentTitle.get(documentTitle.size() - 1).toString().equals(elements.get(2).getText())
                    && documentTitle.get(documentTitle.size() - 2).toString().equals(elements.get(1).getText())
                    && documentTitle.get(documentTitle.size() - 3).toString().equals(elements.get(0).getText())) {
                isStudyMaterialRepeat = true;
            }
            if (isStudyMaterialRepeat) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return documentTitle;
    }
```

After scrolling till bottom I am checking it's a same elements
This logic will scroll till the bottom of the page and if it found last 3 elements are same with stored element it will break the loop

Comment: Can you add more explanation about your answer?

Comment: This logic will scroll till the bottom of the page and if it found last 3 elements are same with stored element it will break the loop