# How to know if bottom/end of a ListView is reached during the ui automation test

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I am trying to perform UI automation test of react-native ios app using appium and Appium-Python-Client.
My problem is I can not know when the bottom of a ListView is reached.
I use `self.driver.swipe()` a few times in a row but it is a hard coded solution.

I checked these so questions:

[Scroll till end of the page using appium-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212411/scroll-till-end-of-the-page-using-appium-android)

[Unable to scroll down till the end of the screen in native ios app using appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466506/unable-to-scroll-down-till-the-end-of-the-screen-in-native-ios-app-using-appium)

But the thing is I do not have any reference element to tell the webdriver when to stop like if `driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id` is true stop swiping.